# How to test `state` changes in stage in jest and enzyme when simulate?

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

How do we test changes in `state` variable in a stage which means I want to test not the final result but also the result in between.

Below is the code I want to test.

```
onLogin = () => {
    this.setState({ isLoggingIn: true }, () => {
        try {
        } catch (err) {
          // Alert.alert(getString('ERROR'), err.message);
        } finally {
            this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false });
        }
    });
}
```

Below is my test code.

```
it('should call onLogin callback', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'onLogin');
    const loginBtn = wrapper.find('#login');
    loginBtn.props().onPress();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(wrapper.instance().state.isLoggingIn).toEqual(false);
    // Attempt => Below I've tried
    // wrapper.update();
    // expect(wrapper.instance().state.isLoggingIn).toEqual(true);
    // wrapper.update();
    // expect(wrapper.instance().state.isLoggingIn).toEqual(false);
```

`wrapper.instance().state.isLoggingIn` is always false. How do I monitor this changes to `false` then `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do we test changes in state variable

We don't. Doing this would:

1. make tests less maintainable
2. hard-code `state` structure in the tests: so unit tests would fail even if everything is fine(more needless work)
3. still keep us unsure if it works at all.

Just test `render()` result and interact with everything it returns. This way you would test what really matters.

Comment: Hm. The coverage is telling me the test of that line is missing tough.

Comment: what exact line?

Comment: Oops sorry. Yes the line was already covered without doing so. Sorry I've had mistake.